# git clone ssh repo in bash shell

Tags: git, bash, shell, ssh, terminal

I'm writing a bash script that includes clone a private repository using SSH,
the problem is when i write `git clone ...` directly in the terminal, it works fine
but in the bash script it's also written `git clone ...` but it gives error

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

any thoughts of what the problem could be?

even if the file contains only:
`sudo git clone git@github.com:username/Project.git`

Comment: Is it the same user running the script? `ssh` is going to use the private key of whoever runs it.

Comment: `sudo` changes things substantially -- in some cases you say you're using it, in some cases you say you're not; be careful to be consistent. Also, it matters whether your current shell has a TTY -- is the script called by cron? Invoked directly? Etc. (Also, naming bash scripts ending in `.sh` is bad practice; see http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful)

Comment: in fact i just tried `echo $USER in both` and they are not the same, the one in the file is root, so i removed the `sudo` from `sudo bash file.sh` and it worked fine, but i need to execute the file as root, can i change user inside the script? if yes, please tell me how, thanks

Comment: Run `git` as yourself, then `sudo chown` and/or `sudo chmod` locally on the files, if necessary. "Execute the file as root" doesn't require ownership change, though; simply `sudo repo/file` to execute `repo/file` as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was,  i just tried echo $USER in both and they are not the same, the one in the file is root, so i removed the sudo from sudo bash file.sh and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code for your script, so it's hard to diagnose.

But some thoughts about what could be different in your script: different current directory, different environment variables, missing hash-bang line loading a different interpreter, different options on the hash-bang line.

Comment: the same problem happens if the .sh file contains only the `git clone git@github.com:...`
and if the file is put any folder